# Drawing strike lines when given strike and dip

Tags: measurements, structural-geology, mapping

Map 1 shows a hillside with topographic contours at 50 m intervals. At Locality A a coal seam is exposed at the surface. The strike and dip of the seam is as indicated on the map. Use this information to draw strike lines for the coal seam and to show where else on the map the seam crops out. Shade the area of the land surface that lies above the coal seam.

How exactly do I work out how to draw the strike lines? The strike and dip is 115/10. What calculation do I use? Also, would the land surface above the coal seam be all the land to the north of it? [image]

Comment: Are you familiar with structure contours?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the homework tag. I will assume it is. I will also assume that the coal seam is not folded. Do you know how to draw (extend) the strike line at the contact? Go ahead and draw a line across your map along strike through the outcrop point. The outcrop is on the 300 m contour. What would the elevation of the coal seam be at other points along that strike line? Where else on the 300 m contour will it outcrop? Can you draw other strike lines elsewhere on the map? From the dip of the seam can you calculate the elevation of the seam along those lines?